# How to pre-load texture atlases for better FPS? IN SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sktextureatlas

Okay, so I have been trying to find answers for this all over the internet and it seems like I almost got it. So what I did is I declared my texture atlases variables outside a class for them to be global throughout my project. Something like this:

```
import SpriteKit
import CoreMotion

let myAtlas1 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "atlas1")
let myAtlas2 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "atlas2")
let myAtlas3 = SKTextureAtlas(named: "atlas3")

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate  {
```

Then, in my GameViewController, I am preloading them, and upon completion I am presenting my GameScene, something like this:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

 class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    SKTextureAtlas.preloadTextureAtlases([myAtlas1, myAtlas2, myAtlas3], withCompletionHandler: {() -> Void in
        NSLog("completed")
        self.startScene()
    })
}

func startScene() {

    let skView = self.view as SKView
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.showsPhysics = false
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    let scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFit
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
    skView.presentScene(scene)

}
```

When I run the game, after my LaunchImage appears, a gray screen pops up, then it takes me to the game. But the player isn't working anymore! Now it isn't able to move or anything else..

Comment: Good question, I'd like to know as well.

If I had to hazard a guess, it'll be part of the GameScene class. From my experience, the GameViewController's job only houses the SKView, and does nothing more in terms of imposing game related stuff.

Comment: Thanks @KelvinLau I've been all over the internet on this and still can't figure out how it works, so if you've found anything so far please let me know!

Comment: If you edit / update your question it might be interesting to put major change below the original question after a little note "EDIT" or "UPDATE". With the major change of the original question others will not understand the answers which are already given. Best wishes :-)

Comment: Hey @Thesaurus03 did you get this issue resolved? Im having an issue to when i preload my textures, upon completion, the block of code doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

In your `GameViewController` instead of starting the `GameScene` immediately, do it in the completion handler.

For example: Create a new game project in Xcode for SpriteKit. In `GameViewController.swift` change the `viewDidLoad` function like this:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // This is not part of the newly created project:
    var tas = [SKTextureAtlas]()
    tas.append(SKTextureAtlas(named: "Ship"))

    // Call the preload and in the completion handler load and start the GameScene:
    SKTextureAtlas.preloadTextureAtlases(tas, withCompletionHandler: { () -> Void in
        NSLog("completed")
        self.startScene()
    })
  }

  // Put the GameScene loading code from viewDidLoad into its own function:
  func startScene() {
    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

(Note that this code references a "Ship.atlas" directory, which needs to be created and is not part of the standard Xcode SpriteKit game project. Also if the texture atlas array is empty, the completion handler will not be called.)

Comment: @RainerScharze, did it now atlases are preloading. But my player isn't working anymore!

Comment: @Thesaurus03 Can you give more details?